# Set Excel Range For Unknown No. Of Columns

Tags: c#, office-interop

As you can see, the no. of columns names generated from column 4 are unknown. How can I set the range, so that I can apply the styles.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
private void OpenExcel()
{
  Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
  Excel.Workbook wb = null;
  Excel.Worksheet ws = null;
  Excel.Range range = null;

  app.visible = true;
  wb = app.Workbooks.Add(1);
   ws = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.WorkSheets[1];
   //range = ws.get_Range("A1","D1");

   ws.Cells[1,1]="Date";
   ws.Cells[1,2]="Code";
   ws.Cells[1,3]="Name";

   IEnumerable<tblCountry> tbl = objDAL.GetRecords();
   int i=4;
   foreach(var item in tbl)
   {
     ws.Cells[1,i] = item.TypeCode;
     i++;
   }
   range.Borders.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black.ToArgb();
   range.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.PeachPuff.ToArgb();
   range.Font.Bold = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `3+ tbl.Count()` as the last column?

```
//remember to initialise tbl first
IEnumerable<tblCountry> tbl = objDAL.GetRecords();
range=ws.get_Range((Excel.Range)ws.Cells[1, 1], (Excel.Range)ws.Cells[1, 3 + tbl.Count()]);
```

Comment: It says, object does not contain a definition for 'get_Range'..int count = 3+tbl.Count();range=ws.get_Range(ws.Cells[1, 1], ws.Cells[1, count]);

Comment: @Ruby, what is your `ws`, get_Range() is a method for `Wooksheet`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.get_range(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Excel.Worksheet ws = null;  ws = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.WorkSheets[1];

Answer (score 1):

Use the `End()` function as follows to select row with all the columns.

```
range = ws.Range("A1").End(xlToLeft).Select
```

And then perform the Style operations.

```
   range.Borders.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black.ToArgb();
   range.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.PeachPuff.ToArgb();
   range.Font.Bold = true;
```

The start range address is "A1" for this example, but I am sure in your Production code, you'll have the Range address as a parameter or coming from a variable.

For a detailed list of `Range` selection operations, see here. http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/ExcelRanges.htm

You can pretty much use any of those VBA methods in this Interop in C#.

Comment: Should it be ["A1"] ? And also, I do not get xlToLeft.

Comment: range = ws.Range["A1"].End[Excel.XlDirection.xlToLeft].Select(); gives an error, cannot convert bool to range. So what should come there?